# Select Dropdown Option is one step behind from rendering

Tags: reactjs

When I click the edit button, the select option of the Department and Position always take the previous value, that says for example first I click the edit button for the A value, next I click it for the B value and they were showing the A value instead of B, and then I click D value and they showed the B value, meaning that they are always one step behind, they will show the old values for each new rendering. I appreciate all answer, thank you.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class InputForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ID: "",
      Email: "",
      Username: "",
      Fullname: "",
      Department: "",
      Position: "",
      Create_Date: "",
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    let value = event.target.value;
    let name = event.target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  handleCreateAccount = () => {
    let accountNew = {
      Department: this.state.Department,
      Email: this.state.Email,
      Fullname: this.state.Fullname,
      ID: this.state.ID,
      Position: this.state.Position,
      Username: this.state.Username,
      Create_Date: this.state.Create_Date,
    };
    this.props.onHandleCreateAccount(accountNew);
  };

  // UPDATE FUNCTION, WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
  handleUpdate = () => {
    var id_Ed = this.props.index + 1;
    this.setState({
      ID: this.props.index + 1,
      Email: this.props.email,
      Username: this.props.username,
      Fullname: this.props.fullname,
      Department: this.props.department,        // SLOWER BY ONE STEP
      Position: this.props.position,            // SLOWER BY ONE STEP
      Create_Date: this.props.create_date,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form">
        <h3>Quản lý nhân viên</h3>
        <form method="POST" id="Main_Form_ID">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label for="">ID: </label>
            <input type="number" required="true" className="form-control" id="ID_ID" name="ID" value={this.state.ID} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label for="">Email: </label>
            <input type="email" required="true" className="form-control" id="Email_ID" name="Email" value={this.state.Email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label for="">Username: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              required="true"
              className="form-control"
              id="Username_ID"
              name="Username"
              value={this.state.Username}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label for="">Fullname: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              required="true"
              className="form-control"
              id="Fullname_ID"
              name="Fullname"
              value={this.state.Fullname}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label for="sel1">Select a Department:</label>
            <select className="form-control" id="Department_ID" name="Department" value={this.state.Department} onChange={this.handleChange}>
              <option>--Select a Department--</option>
              <option>Accounting</option>
              <option>Business Development</option>
              <option>Engineering</option>
              <option>Human Resources</option>
              <option>Research and Development</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label for="sel1">Select a Position:</label>
            <select className="form-control" id="Position_ID" name="Position" value={this.state.Position} onChange={this.handleChange}>
              <option>--Select a Position--</option>
              <option>Developer</option>
              <option>Tester</option>
              <option>Scrum Master</option>
              <option>PM</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label for="">Create_Date: </label>
            <input
              type="date"
              required="true"
              className="form-control"
              id="Cretate_Date_ID"
              name="Create_Date"
              value={this.state.Create_Date}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input type="button" className="btn btn-success" value="CreateAccount" onClick={this.handleCreateAccount} />

            <input type="button" className="btn btn-success" id="update_btn" value="Update" />

            <input type="reset" className="btn btn-warning" id="Edit_ID" value="Edit" onClick={this.handleUpdate} />

            <input type="reset" className="btn btn-success" id="reset_btn" value="Reset" />

            <input type="button" className="btn btn-danger" id="reset_btn" value="Close" onClick={this.handleClose} />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default InputForm;
```

Comment: It's now slow. Select will be one step backwards as when you select current it will show the last selected item.
it you uses this data in API it will be working absolutely fine.Currently selected option will be there .

Comment: My teacher is using the fake api from reactjs itself and save it to the local storage to demonstrate the lecture, so there's no way to fix it, kinda weird, thank you so much for answering.

Comment: You just save it to localStorage when checked output will be correct.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).